# One single PLSQL function with CLOB or VARCHAR2 input and CLOB or VARCHAR2 return value

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I need to write a PLSQL function which has to work on both CLOB and VARCHAR2 inputs and return CLOB or VARCHAR2 respectively. But the functionality implemented by the function is exactly the same (it does a series of REGEXP_REPLACE calls) regardless of the input type. Is it possible to write a function which can accept both CLOB and VARCHAR2 at the same time and return the type received? I want to avoid writing two very similar functions, thus duplicating the code.

My first function is something like:

```
FUNCTION Test(i_text CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS
v_text CLOB;
BEGIN
  v_text := i_text;  
  ... a series of REGEXP_REPLACE calls like v_text := REGEXP_REPLACE(v_text,...)
  RETURN v_text
END;
```

And my other function is:

```
FUNCTION Test(i_text VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
v_text VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
  v_text := i_text;  
  ... a series of REGEXP_REPLACE calls like v_text := REGEXP_REPLACE(v_text,...)
  RETURN v_text
END;
```

As there are a good number of REGEXP_REPLACE calls inside the functions, I'd prefer to have only one function - if possible.

CLOB inputs can be of significant size, so converting CLOB to VARCHAR2 before the function call is not possible.

Even REGEXP_REPLACE works on various inputs, like CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, CLOB or NCLOB. So that's why I hope there is a solution for this need.

Comment: Bear in mind that regex operations will be extremely slow on clobs. Using the built-in capabilities provided by DBMS_LOB may be more efficient (depending on how you want to manipulate the input string). Given that you should consider whether the performance benefits of two different functions outweighs the maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@BarbarosOzhan is correct that you need a package to get the overload capability. But you do not need to duplicate the code. While you are correct in that converting a CLOB to VARCHAR2 is not possible there is nothing preventing you casting a VARCHAR2 to a CLOB.  Then, providing you do not extend the length in the regular expressions, convert the result back to a VARCHAR2. The function handling a varchar2 then just becomes a wrapper that just handls the conversions.

```
create or replace package test_pkg is
    function test(i_text clob) return clob;
    function test(i_text varchar2) return varchar2;
end test_pkg;   
/

create or replace package body test_pkg is
    function test(i_text clob) return clob is
      v_text clob;
    begin
      v_text := i_text;  
      --...
      return v_text;
    end test;
    
    function test(i_text varchar2) return varchar2 is
      v_text clob;
      v_res  varchar2(32767);   -- 4000 is actually used in SQL statement
    begin
       v_text := cast(i_text as clob); 
       v_res := cast (test(v_text) as varchar2);
       return v_res;
    end test;
end test_pkg;
```

Your calling routine should expect and handle the exception "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"

Comment: Thanks @Belayer. This is great, I did not know that casting from VARCHAR2 to CLOB is so easy. This solved my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. I didn't know that either - never actually done it. But it seemed logical after all a CLOB is basically a very long VARCHAR2. Many years ago I learned a vary useful technique, it's called "beneficial wishful thinking". It comes out of Psychology but for development it basically translates to "I wish I could do X", so write a piece of code that does X. If it works then you can do it; if not move on.

Comment: I like such positive thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a package with two `Test`(*Overloading in Packages*) functions such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Pkg_Test IS
  FUNCTION Test (i_text VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
  FUNCTION Test (i_text CLOB) RETURN CLOB;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Pkg_Test IS
  FUNCTION Test (i_text VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   val VARCHAR2;
  BEGIN
   SELECT ...
     INTO val
     FROM tab t
    WHERE t.col1 = i_text;
    
   RETURN val; 
  END;

  FUNCTION Test (i_text CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS
   val CLOB;
  BEGIN
   SELECT ....
     INTO val
     FROM tab t
    WHERE t.col2 = i_text;
    
   RETURN val; 
  END;
END;
/
```

and call with the same name as below whatever the data type of the parameter is

```
BEGIN
  :result := Pkg_Test.test(:prm);
END;
/
```

Comment: Yes, I know about procedure overloading, this is what I'm doing now. But even in this case I will have to duplicate the long series of (REGEXP_REPLACE or whatever) calls. Because even in this case you have two separate functions with two separate bodies. And both will have the same large set of calls inside the body. This is what I'm trying to avoid somehow.